# Is there a max img size able to render to html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

I am trying to read in a jpg and render the image to an HTML5 canvas and then grab and store the data as a DataURL. I am wondering is there a maximum size image that can be rendered into a canvas. It works with with files 5mb and smaller but when I try for instance a 10mb jpg when I open the resulting dataURI in a new tab it is just black. I posted the basic logic for what I am doing below.

```
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {

      var finalCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = finalCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
        finalCanvas.width = img.width;
        finalCanvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Get data URL and compress image 75%
        finalImagedocument = finalCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.75); 
        console.log(finalImagedocument);
      }
      img.src = reader.result;

    }

    filedata = reader.readAsDataURL(f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size for a canvas element is 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB
     RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM

Comment: How did you arrive at these figures?